# Forgot to notify Immigration Bureau of Japan about job transfer

Tags: employment, japan, bureaucracy

Today I find out that I'm supposed to notify the Immigration Bureau of Japan within 14 days of my job transfer. 
I'm about 1 month late now, am I toasted?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In principle, you could face a fine of up to 200,000 yen (that's in the same category as, for example, not carrying your residence card when you go out); in practice I have never heard of anybody who was fined for this. In any case, you do not face imprisonment or deportation (that would have been the case if you had made a false notification, as opposed to no notificstion at all).

The requirement for this notification is set forth in [Article 19-16 of the Immigration Act](http://www.japaneselawtranslation.go.jp/law/detail_main?re=&vm=&id=2647#en_ch4sc1sb2at14), which reads:

> (Notification Relating to the Organization of Affiliation, etc.)
>
> Article 19-16　Any mid to long resident who is residing in Japan with a
>   status of residence listed in the following items shall, where the
>   cause provided for in the respective item occurs with regard to the
>   category of the status of residence listed therein, notify the
>   Minister of Justice to such effect and of the matters provided for in
>   an Ordinance of the Ministry of Justice in accordance with the
>   procedures provided for in the Ordinance of the Ministry of Justice
>   within 14 days of the date of the occurrence of such cause.
>
> (i)　"Professor", "Highly Skilled Professional" (limited to those
>   pertaining to item (i), sub-item (c) or item (ii) (limited to cases of
>   engaging in the activities listed in sub-item (c) of the same item) in
>   the right-hand column under "Highly Skilled Professional" of Appended
>   Table I (2)), "Business Manager", " Legal/Accounting Services",
>   "Medical Services", "Instructor", Intra-company Transferee",
>   "Technical Intern Training", "Student" or "Trainee":　change in the
>   name or location, or extinction of the public or private organization
>   in Japan at which the activities listed respectively in the right-hand
>   column of Appended Table I with regard to the status of residence are
>   being carried out, or when leaving or being transferred from the
>   organization.
>
> (ii)　"Highly Skilled Professional (limited to those
>   pertaining to item (i), sub-item (a) or (b) or item (ii) (limited to
>   cases of engaging in the activities listed in sub-item (a) or (b) of
>   the same item) in the right-hand column under "Highly Skilled
>   Professional" of Appended Table I (2)), "Researcher",
>   "Engineer/Specialist in Humanities/ International Services",
>   "Entertainer" (limited to cases of engaging in the activities
>   pertaining to the status of residence based on a contract with a
>   public or private organization in Japan) or "Skilled Labor":　change in
>   the name or location, or extinction of the public or private
>   organization in Japan which is the other party to the contract (with
>   regard to the status of residence of "Highly Skilled Professional"
>   (limited to those pertaining to item (i), sub-item (a) in the
>   right-hand column under "Highly Skilled Professional" of the same
>   Table), the public or private organization in Japan designated by the
>   Minister of Justice), or the termination of the contract or conclusion
>   of a new contract with the organization.
>
> (iii)　"Dependent" (limited to
>   those pertaining to persons who are able to engage in daily activities
>   as a spouse), "Spouse or Child of Japanese National" (limited to those
>   pertaining to persons with the status of the spouse of a Japanese
>   national) or "Spouse or Child of Permanent Resident" (limited to those
>   pertaining to persons with the status of the spouse of a person
>   residing with the status of residence of "Permanent Resident" or
>   "Special Permanent Resident" (hereinafter referred to as "Permanent
>   Resident, etc."):　death of or divorce from the spouse.

And the fine of up to 200,000 yen for not fulfilling this requirement is set forth in [Article 71-3](http://www.japaneselawtranslation.go.jp/law/detail_main?re=&vm=&id=2647#ja_ch12at5):

> Article 71-3　Any person who falls under any of the following items
>   shall be punished with a fine not exceeding 200,000 yen.
>
> [...]
>
> (iii)　A person who has violated the provisions of Article 19-10,
>   paragraph (1), Article 19-15 (except for paragraph (4)) or Article
>   19-16.

Comment: Do you have a source / reference / personal experience for this?

Comment: In fact, the answer was wrong... I have corrected it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your details answer. It seems that I get off scot-free this time. I've added my case as an additional answer.

Comment: Just to add my case, I've notified my change of job after 6 months, my both notices were accepted. I've used e-Notification System. And surely I made mistake, but on other hand no Japanese Employer has any checklist regarding Job changing notice. I was not able to notify because I was not aware about such rule. But when I get to know I immediately done it. So we should never afraid of doing right thing.

Answer (score 10):

fkraiem has already provided a fantastic answer, I just want to add my personal experience.

Yesterday I notified the Immigration Bureau of Japan via their e-system. They said on their site that additional inquiry will be made if deemed necessary. However, I've received an email today which only said that my notification has been recorded. I guess I'm clear now.

Just in case someone stumbled on this question later, here's the link to their e-system, just click on the orange button on the lower left corner. I really recommend that, saved me a trip to Shinagawa and from taking a day off.

http://www.immi-moj.go.jp/i-ens/faq/faq_a_ja.html